# Jackson 2.0 Mapper returns wrong Date format

Tags: json, timestamp, jackson, pojo

i use a postgresql database and i save there a normal "timestamp without timezone" value.

this looks like this in my database:
2014-05-09 16:04:01.889

now i have created a pojo with a JsonFormat annoation to format my timestamp:

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd.MM.yyyy,HH:mm")
private Timestamp date;
```

but this returns me:

date": "09.05.2014,14:04"

The hours are wrong, it should be 16 and not 14.. what do i wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

The difference in hours definitely comes from the difference in the time zones. According to [the Jackson Date/Time FAQ](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling), Jackson uses the GMT timezone by default. I suggest you  to follow the wiki page and [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9839392/3537858) to fix the handling of the date/time in your application.