# I'm trying to convert string of format "2019-11-15T18:30:00Z" to Date Format.I have attached the code as well

Tags: java, java-time, date-conversion

```
String data = "2019-11-15T18:30:00Z";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(data, formatter);
System.out.println(data + "\t" + date);
```

When I try to print the converted date I'm not getting the date in Desired format.

`Output: 2019-11-15T18:30:00Z 2019-11-15T18:30`

Why is the seconds part and 'Z' is missing in the converted date

Comment: Please edit question and add language tag. Else, will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different explanations for the two parts you are missing:

1. > Why is the seconds part

   `LocalDateTime.toString()` (implicitly called when you concatenate the date time to a string) leaves out seconds if they (and fraction of second) are zero. To quote the documentation:

   > The format used will be the shortest that outputs the full value of
   >   the time where the omitted parts are implied to be zero.
2. > and 'Z' is missing in the converted date

   The `Z` in the original string is an offset (of zero) from UTC. A `LocalDateTime` hasn’t got a UTC offset, so when parsing into a `LocalDateTime` you are losing this piece of information. To quote the documentation again a `LocalDateTime` is:

   > A date-time without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such
   >   as 2007-12-03T10:15:30.

To preserve the offset, use `OffsetDateTime` instead of `LocalDateTime`:

```
    String data = "2019-11-15T18:30:00Z";
    OffsetDateTime date = OffsetDateTime.parse(data);
    System.out.println(data + "\t" + date);
```

Output:

> 2019-11-15T18:30:00Z  2019-11-15T18:30Z

It’s still without the seconds. To print them even though they are zero, use a `DateTimeFormatter` like the one you were already using, only for formatting:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
    System.out.println(data + "\t" + date.format(formatter));
```

> 2019-11-15T18:30:00Z  2019-11-15T18:30:00Z

Only never hardcode `Z` as a literal in your format pattern string. As I said, it’s an offset. If you hardcode it, you will also print `Z` when one day you have got an `OffsetDateTime` with a different offset, and your output will be downright wrong. Instead use pattern letter `X` for offset.

### Links

- [Documentation of `LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)
- [Documentation of `LocalDateTime.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString())
- A closely related question: [Parsing timestamp as LocalDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54941872/parsing-timestamp-as-localdatetime)
- Another related question: [Format LocalDateTime with Timezone in Java8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561377/format-localdatetime-with-timezone-in-java8)

Comment: The solution is well documented.Appreciate the way you have explained