# Jackson incorrectly deserialize Joda dates with custom date format

Tags: java, jackson, jodatime

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize quite simple object with custom date format:

```
public class DateTimeTest {
    private static final String DATE_PATTERN = "yyyyMMdd";

    public static DateTime date = DateTime.now();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer();

        String str = writer.writeValueAsString(new Domain());
        System.out.println(str);

        ObjectReader reader = mapper.reader(Domain.class);
        Domain domain = reader.readValue(str);

        System.out.println(domain.getDate());
    }

    private static class Domain {
        @JsonFormat(pattern = DATE_PATTERN)
        private DateTime date;

        public Domain() {
            this.date = DateTime.now();
        }

        public DateTime getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(DateTime date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
    }
}
```

While executing main method I'm expecting to get something similar to:

> "date":"20151117"
>   20151117

But unfortunately get the following:

> {"date":"20151117"}
>   **20151117**-01-01T00:00:00.000+03:00 (**year is incorrect**)

Seems that Jackson ignores @JsonFormat annotation for objects deserialization and treat the string as date in ISO-8601 notation. Does anyone know the fix?

```
<jackson.version>2.5.4</jackson.version>
<jodatime.version>2.8.1</version>
```

UPDATE: If I change date pattern to "dd/MM/yyyy", then I even start getting error "IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format". So for sure Jackson ignores date pattern for deserialization.

Comment: Saw your answer below, in your case is an upgrade possible? Or did you need a fix for that specific Jackson version?

Comment: Yes, finally I'm upgraded and the code works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Jackson Release Notes](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.6) support for Joda @JsonFormat(pattern=...) for deserialization was added only from 2.6.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the shape to the JsonFormat

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = DATE_PATTERN)
```

Comment: Doesn't work - the result is the same. "20151117-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" instead of "2015-11-17".

Comment: @DzmitryZahusta Change your pattern to this `yyyy-MM-dd` Also you might wanna look into the [@Temporal](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4065) annotation if you have different Date Objects

Comment: I cannot change date pattern. It comes to me from third system. And i'm expecting to get "20151117" date string.

Answer (score 0):

```js
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
```

if exact pattern format not coming try this

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling

[Set Jackson Timezone for Date deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556851/set-jackson-timezone-for-date-deserialization/9839392#9839392)

as am not sure even when u keeping formate den also result not obtained...go through the above link..it may help u

Comment: It won't work for me as I need exactly that date format as I wrote - "yyyyMMdd". I'm expecting that DateTime will be serialized and deserialized corectly in both side.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem? You got correct serialization and deserealization. The output "20151117-01-01T00:00:00.000+03:00" it is just the result of DateTime.toString().