# java Gson json formatter, is it possible to ouptput Z instead of +0000?

Tags: java, json, gson

I need to read in some json, sort it, then output it again.   I am using this to de-seralise and serialise the json:

```
    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
        .create();
```

If I parse this to a Date:

```
"activedDate": "2021-04-20T21:48:04.107Z",
```

Then output it again as Json, I get this:

```
"activedDate": "2021-04-20T21:48:04.107+0000",
```

But I need it to have Z instead of +0000 if possible.

Is this possible (without hacking the resultant strings)?

I am forcing my laptop to UTC thusly:

```
java -Duser.timezone=UTC  -jar my.jar
```

Comment: Set the format to `..SSS'Z'`?

Comment: My assumption is that this would add a static char "Z" regardless of the timezone?  If the timezone happened to be +1000, then it should not show Z in this case...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8405087/2541560 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/7556851/2541560

Comment: Thanks, but those two are both for the de-serialisation, which works fine. Its the serialization which is not working as desired.

Comment: That's completely irrelevant since your issue is with date formatting.

Comment: Date formatting works fine in de-serialiseation: I can read Z ok. I just cant get gson to write it. Those posts do not address this unfortunately.

Comment: Unfortunately for you, I guess. Many people can get a lot of information out of them. You're not making a lot of effort to solve your own problem, are you?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `X`. From [the DateTimeFormatter docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
   X       zone-offset 'Z' for zero    offset-X          Z; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15;
```

So a format string like `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX` will give you a date like `2022-07-26T16:46:35.247Z`.